# Firefox WebIDE simulator option missing

Tags: firefox, web-ide

When i open Firefox, open WebIDE from Developer and found 'Simulators' tab missing.

Screenshot from my Firefox  ( WebIDE )
[image: screenshot from my machine firefox - WebIDE]

Screenshot from net where 'Simulators' tab present.
[image]